# How to set the data length for SPI communication in Arduino library?

Tags: serial, spi, data

How can I set the number of bits that need to be transferred in SPI communication from a Slave chip to Master MCU using Arduino SPI Library in a SPI transaction? Let us say I want to read 14-bits data from Slave into my Master Arduino MCU then how would set this 14-bits in the SPI Library?

Comment: You don't. You transfer multiples of 8 bits. In general you would transfer 16 and discard or ignore 2.